# Length of digits of an integer with leading zeros

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a number with leading zeros say 00000006906. I want the number of digit in this number as 11. I tried

```
var num = 00000006906;
num.length// always outputs 4
```

and

```
num.toString().length// always outputs 4
```

length but it is always returning as 4 because javascript always treats it as 6906. This number comes from user input and I need to validate this. Consider this number as the reference number and always it is expected to have leading zeros with 11 digits. I want to check the number of digits only because I want to validate whether it is satisfying the required format. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Dont convert the input into an int until you need it to be.

Comment: numbers don't have leading zeroes, numbers have only a value. `00000006906 === 6906` if you want leading zeroes, then you have to use a string. *"Consider this number as the reference number and always it is expected to have leading zeros with 11 digits"* then logically this ain't a number, but a string of digits

Comment: I don't see the issue here with it being a string seeing as it's user input so it starts off as a string to being with and there's no arithmetic going on. OP clearly has no idea what the F their doing.

Comment: Also if OP had a brain cell they would have seen that it doesn't matter since it will always expect there to be leading zeros. OP's code could easily add the leading zeros to satisfy the 11 digit requirement and will save bytes if their storing this. Since I'm going to assume this is simply for display purposes seeing as arithmetic doesn't care and certainly a database lookup either.

Comment: @Bimal, Do you know that `leading zeros in js means octal, i.e. 0012 === 10`? How you are receiving this input? Show your code. You are just wasting people's time here.

Answer (score 1):

Do consider the input as string, do not restrict it to be an integer otherwise JavaScript will always remove leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but a solution/workaround for your problem by enforcing the required pattern.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.onfocus = function(){
  input.selectionEnd = input.selectionStart = 11;
}
input.oninput = function(){
  input.value = input.value.match(/^\s*0*(\d{0,11})/)[1].padStart(11, 0);
};
```

```css
input:valid {
  background-color: #CFC;
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: #FCC;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
reference number: 
<input value="00000000000" pattern="^\d{11}$" />
</label>
```